# Creating a simple menu for Arduino LCD button shield

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

I am trying to create a very simple menu to use with my lcd keypad shield, I have tried looking into how tutorials say to do this but I don’t really understand them.

Would it be possible to do it by doing something like creating an integer I.e menuTotal, that depending on the what the value of menuTotal is a menu item would display, then have the the up and down buttons add or subtract 1  of the menuTotal value.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Liam

Comment: Rather than using a LCD which has commonly 2 lines, I suggest to use a small Oled display. After that, your problem is pure code. Take a sheet of paper, simulate what you want to display and you'll find variable you need, when to inc, when to dec and so on.

Comment: `I don’t really understand them` ... you need to learn the basics first

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of holding the "current" menu selection and incrementing or decrementing upon external input (button press) is a sound approach.

Consider writing a `drawMenu()` function that draws the screen, based on the current menu. In your program, keep a `bool updateScreen` variable. Then, any time you get an external input that would change the screen, set the `updateScreen` variable to `true`.  The actual `drawMenu()` function, after drawing the screen, should reset the `updateScreen` variable back to `false`.

In your `loop()` function, have a section like:

```
loop() {
  // [... other code ...]

  if (updateScreen) {
    drawMenu();
  }

  // [... other code ...]
}
```

In this way, the screen is updated when necessary, and your main loop can keep running, processing input, etc.