# What does drawmenu() mean

Tags: arduino-mega, programming

Can anybody tell me what drawmenu() means, I got an answer on here that has the term on and I don’t quite understand it, I’m very new to this.

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Liam

Comment: It calls the function `drawmenu()` that is included in some code somewhere.  Does your code have any interesting `#include ...` statements?

Comment: the code I am writing is to create a simple menu for my Arduino LCD push button shield, so I will be using #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a simple menu for Arduino LCD button shield](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48904/creating-a-simple-menu-for-arduino-lcd-button-shield)

Answer (score 2):

I gave you [that particular answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48904/creating-a-simple-menu-for-arduino-lcd-button-shield)

The function `drawMenu()` has no meaning. I was suggesting that you **create** a function with that name, whose action is to write text to the LCD with your selected menu item. The name of the function is not relevant. It does not exist until you create it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i wasn't sure whether i should ask this question in the comments on the other page or start a new thread. I understand now, thank you.